# NoSuchAnnotation("declarations")

Tags: rascal

```
rascal>import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;
ok
rascal>import lang::java::jdt::m3::AST;
ok
rascal>import lang::ofg::ast::Java2OFG;
ok
rascal>m = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://Tool/eLib|);
|plugin://rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/analysis/m3/Registry.rsc|(1296,5,<37,51>,<37,56>): 
   NoSuchAnnotation("declarations")
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a bug report, see github issue tracker, but could it be that you've installed an unstable release instead of the stable release?